# Closing colorbox within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I tried opening a colorbox once a user submits a form by doing the following:

```
$.colorbox({
    'iframe': true,
    'width':'550px',
    'height':'200px', 
    'href': 'index.html', 
    'onClosed': function()
    { 
        var form$ = $('#book-form');
        form$.get(0).submit();
    }
});
```

and I'm trying to close it within the iframe by doing the following (when people click on the "Yes" link):

```
$('#yes').click(function() 
{ 
    parent.$('#repeat_provider').val(" . $booking['provider_id'] . ");

    parent.$.colorbox.close();

    return true;
});
```

but the colorbox is not actually closing. Not sure what I did wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error in console? You may try `parent.$.fn.colorbox.close()`

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work, but there is a couple of things you need to keep in mind.

If you are binding this click event to an anchor element, you need to handle the default behavior.  And if you divorced the $ alias from jQuery in your parent document, you need to remember to use jQuery.

```
$('#yes').click(function() 
{ 
    parent.jQuery('#repeat_provider').val("whatever");
    parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
    return false; // cancel the default click event
});
```